# How to get the pointer of a pcl:PolygonMesh object

Tags: c++, pointers

I am a total newbie in C++ and PCL. I try to use `meshDecim.setInputMesh()` which needs a `pcl::PolygonMesh::Ptr`. I have got `pcl::PolygonMesh`.

```
pcl::PolygonMesh triangles; 
pcl::PolygonMesh::Ptr meshOutput(new pcl::PolygonMesh()); 
pcl::PolygonMesh::Ptr inp_ptr; 
inp_ptr = triangles;                                           /////???? 
pcl::MeshQuadricDecimationVTK meshDecim; 
meshDecim.setInputMesh(inp_ptr);                     ///// from triangles 
meshDecim.setTargetReductionFactor(0.5); 
meshDecim.process(*meshOutput);
```

Comment: Well, to get a pointer to something you stick a `&` in front of it, i.e. `&triangles`

Comment: @Sean See image below

Answer (score 3):

To receive the memory address of something you use the `&` operator. Example:

```
pcl::PolygonMesh::Ptr inptr = &triangles;
```

Or you could just pass `&triangles` in `meshDecim.SetInputMesh(&triangles);`.

Comment: I tried this but it does not work. 

        // would work
 pcl::PolygonMesh::Ptr inp_ptr(new pcl::PolygonMesh());
 boost::shared_ptr<pcl::PolygonMesh> tt;http://fs5.directupload.net/images/160624/pbahjo4f.png